# Is there a way of escaping or managing tokens in free text?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have a lexer grammar like this:

```
lexer grammar MyGrammarLexer;

OPEN  : '{' -> pushMode (textMode);
OTHER : . -> skip ;

mode textMode ;

CLOSE : '}' -> popMode ;
TEXT : . ;
```

And a grammar like this:

```
parser grammar MyGrammarParser;

options { 
  tokenVocab = MyGrammarLexer ;
}

parse : OPEN text CLOSE EOF ;

text : TEXT* ;
```

Which is fine until i have a `'}'` as part of the text/TEXT. 
Therefore is there a standard way of managing this? 
I think there should be a way of escaping it like having `'\}'` in the parsed text but i cannot find an example.

Comment: What if instead of . for your TEXT rule, you used ~[}]* ?

Comment: Also note that the grammar above does not handle nested { and } such as { { } }. I am not sure if you require that.

Comment: Wouldnt using the negation still cause the lexer to stop matching at the first } ? Also i dont need to have any nesting...

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood the question apologies for the incorrect response. Yes you are correct, it would stop at the first }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognising `\}` as a `}` character inside `TEXT` would work fine. Thrn you would have to consider the question of how you represent a `\` inside `TEXT`. A common answer is to use `\\`.

But that's all your decision. You could use some quoting character other than `\`, if you wanted to. You could insist on hex escapes, as in URLs, where `%xx` represents the character whose character code is `xx` in hexadecimal. You could use HTML-style entities, although in this case you get to think up your own name, maybe `&close;`. (Or you could just use a numeric entity like `&#125;`.)

Part of designing an input format (or language) consists of answering questions like this. ANTLR makes no attempt to impose an answer; all it does is provide you with a mechanism to implement whatever quoting rule you think is appropriate. That mechanism is not at all mysterious; it simply consists of writing a pattern which you will recognise, and associating that pattern with an action, if desired (such as inserting the quoted character into the TEXT).

Comment: defining the escape '\}' before the CLOSE works for me. Of course this means some pre/post processing that can be done outside of the lexer/parser.